# R Auto Zoom Updated leafletProxy Map object in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am experimenting with the `leaflet` package for some maps in Shiny.  I would like to be able to have a base map that data will change and subsequently be remapped.  However, I am trying to use the `leafletProxy` function whereby there is a base map and I just change the data points that are added.  All of this works however the map doesn't zoom to the datapoints location.  It remains at the farthest zoom.

[image]

The code to reproduce the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  actionButton("goButton", "New Points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      )
  })

  observeEvent(input$goButton, {
    points <- cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)

    leafletProxy('mymap', session) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(data = points)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like the map to automatically zoom in once new points have been added.

Answer (score 5):

try to add argument "fitBounds" in leafletProxy()

```
leafletProxy('mymap', session) %>%
  clearMarkers() %>%
  addMarkers(data = points) %>%
  fitBounds(lng1 = max(points$long),lat1 = max(points$lat),
            lng2 = min(points$long),lat2 = min(points$lat))
```

Answer (score 1):

I revised G. Cocca's answer (mostly by adding a dataframe of "points") to get this:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  actionButton("goButton", "New Points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      )
  })

  observeEvent(input$goButton, {
    points <- data.frame("long" = rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, 
                            "lat" = rnorm(40) + 48)


    leafletProxy('mymap', session) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(data = points) %>%
      fitBounds(lng1 = max(points$long),lat1 = max(points$lat),
                lng2 = min(points$long),lat2 = min(points$lat))


  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You call `leafletProxy`  twice in the `observeEvent`. You can delete the first code block.

Comment: Excellent catch, @SeGa. I revised.